# svn: E175002: REPORT of '/xxxx-demo/!svn/vcc/default': Could not read response body: Secure connection truncated

Tags: svn

SVN sometimes returns this error -

> svn: E175002: REPORT of '/synapse-demo/!svn/vcc/default': Could not read response body: Secure connection truncated

when trying to update a repo. Probably caused due to a large update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Performing a simple "svn cleanup" followed by an "svn update" again will solve your problem.